# Is it good to throw an exception object by reference

Tags: c++, exception

Well I have been reading [this](http://www.acodersjourney.com/2016/08/top-15-c-exception-handling-mistakes-avoid/?utm_content=buffer7affd&utm_medium=social&utm_source=facebook.com&utm_campaign=buffer) article that talks about avoiding exception handling mistakes, it seems fine but the one point I stuck for a clarification is,with that being said

> When an exception is thrown and control passes from a try block to a
>   handler, the C++ run time calls destructors for all automatic objects
>   constructed since the beginning of the try block.

And an another point it seemingly suggests getting thrown object by reference in a catch is good practice since it avoid memory management and copying, what seems odd to me is

```
try
{

Object o;
//make error..
throw ref(o);
}catch(Object & p)
{
//do some handle..
}
```

when compared with what that is said, will it be good to go with the above code? doesn't all the object constructed inside the try unwound when it reaches throw..or it will unwind after the catch?

Comment: Throw values. Catch references.

Comment: What? From the reference: "Mistake # 6: Not Throwing an exception by value",

Answer (score 3):

> Is it good to throw an exception object by reference?

No. It isn't. In your example `o` will be destroyed as part of stack unwinding after throw, so you will catch a dangling reference.

Do what article says and throw by value: `throw o;`, `throw std::move(o);` (if `o` is cheap-to-move-hard-to-copy ) or move exception tuning in separate function and do something like `throw make_error(/*...*/)`. This will throw a copy of object `o` *which has separate lifetime and which will not be destroyed by stack unwinding* until it is handled.

You should catch exception by reference (`catch Object& o`) to avoid extra copy of exception object and potential slicing.

So you should throw objects by value (to avoid lifetime issues) and catch by reference (avoid slicing and extra copy)